# Android - Expand view's height and width

Tags: android

I am using a RelativeLayout in my android studio project and I want it to expand both sides (height and width) simultaneously. I have the initial height (0dp) and final height (130dp), initial width(0dp) and final width (250dp). I have copied a code for expanding its height from 0dp - 130dp and its working fine. I just want to know how can I modify it to consider the width parameters also.
Here is my code for expanding height. I have used ValueAnimator for the task.

MainActivity.java

```
 public  static void expand(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight, int targetWidth){
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, targetHeight);
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
```

And I am calling this method from onClickListener for the button like this:

```
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //cv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 130, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 250, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                expand(cv, 100, height, width);
            }
        });
```

`
where cv is my RelativeLayout whose height and width I want to expand.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use a more simple approach for animation ,using animation and animation utils class such as following

1. Create a new directory under res such following

right click on res->new->android resource directory->then select resource type as anim(you can change directory name also,do not change anything else).

2. Then create a new xml file(i have zoom_in.xml) under that newly created directory and put below code in it,

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0dp"
        android:fromYScale="0dp"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="4000"
        android:toXScale="250dp"
        android:toYScale="130dp"
        >

    </scale>
</set>
```

3. Then in button click event use the animation as following,

   ```
       ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       Animation a1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.zoom_in);//here zoom_in.xml is placed inside res/anim(i have anim name ,you can have yours)/zoom_in
       cv.startAnimation(a1);

       }
   });
   ```
4. for more information go to https://www.journaldev.com/9481/android-animation-example

Comment: its working now. I just had to change the values of xml file a bit according to my requirement. Thank you.